# Custom git hook in package.json with husky

Tags: git, package.json, git-husky

I am trying to validate the commit message at commit. For that, I am using Husky and the commit-msg hook.

However, as I also do commit message validation at build time, I want the validation code to be available in a separate JS file. So I am trying to call an external JS file to perform my commit validation. In my package.json file, I have:

```
"commitmsg": "node validation.js"
```

However, I cannot get the validation to be performed properly. Right now, validation.js looks like this:

```
console.log('Here');
const config = (a, b) => {
  console.log(a);
  console.log(b);
};

module.exports = config;
```

`Here` is displayed, but the `console.log`s in the function are not called.

Any idea how I can get my function to get called? Also, how can I access the commit message?

Comment: _"However, as I also do commit message validation at build time"_ but why? If a pre-commit hook validates messages, how is it ever possible to have a commit message that fails this build check, which must necessarily come after the git hook?

Comment: The checks are a bit different. We have multiple formats for commit messages, and at least one "conventional commit message" must be present in a feature branch. Same rules, but additional checks.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was being silly, I found the solution. In case it is useful to somebody else in the future:

```
const myRegex = new RegExp('.*');
const commitMsg = require('fs').readFileSync(process.env.HUSKY_GIT_PARAMS, 'utf8');

if (!myRegex.test(commitMsg) ) {
  console.error(`Invalid commit message!`);
  process.exit(1);
}
```