# How to create custom husky hook? (node.js/package.json)

Tags: husky

How to create custom husky hook?

I would like to do something like this:

```
// package.json
...
husky: {
  "pre-commit": "node customHook.js"
},
...
```

How to get access to the commit params from the customHook.js file?

P.S. I found almost the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49980533/custom-git-hook-in-package-json-with-husky), but unfortunately it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

Change "pre-commit" hook to "commit-msg" in the `package.json` file. After, you are able to get commit message by using the next line of code:

```
// terminal (cmd)
git commit -m "my commit message"
```

```
// customHook.js file
const message = require('fs').readFileSync(process.env.HUSKY_GIT_PARAMS, 'utf-8');

console.log(message); // "my commit message"
```

Comment: Can you reject the commit for example if regex of commit is not correct? In `customHook.js` can you exit the process if some conditions are not met and commit is prevented?

Comment: @mjakic inside your js file you can throw a js Error which would result in the hook throwing and error and your script failing.

Comment: you can use **process.exit(1)**